# Why is Fourier transform on $L^1(G)$ defined as $\int f(x) \gamma(x^{-1}) dx$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, abelian-groups, locally-compact-groups

Why is Fourier transform of $f\in L^1(G)$ defined as $\hat{f}(\gamma)=\int f(x) \gamma(x^{-1}) dx$ instead of  $\int f(x) \gamma(x) dx$?

Here $G$ is a locally compact abelian group,  $\gamma$ is a continuous character on $G$, i.e., a continuous homomorphism that maps G to $\mathbb{T}$ . $\int f(x) \gamma(x) dx$ seems more natural if we view $\gamma$ as a linear functional on $L^1(G)$.

Comment: It let you write something like $\langle f,\gamma \rangle = \int_G f(x) \gamma(x^{-1})d\mu(x)$ such that $f = \int_{\widehat{G}} \langle f,\gamma \rangle \gamma d\nu(\gamma)$, see [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Fourier_transform_and_Fourier_inversion_formula_for_L1-functions)

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}, $ $\hat{f}(\xi)=\int f(x)e^{-2i\pi x \xi} dx$, if we let $\gamma(x)=e^{-2i\pi x \xi}$, it is still a character and $\hat{f}(\gamma)=\int f(x) \gamma(x) dx$. So I don't think it is a convention here.

Comment: I think the notation $\langle f,\gamma \rangle = \int_G f(x) \overline{\gamma(x)} d\mu(x)$ would be better then

Answer (score 0):

Update, One may define Fourier transform by $\hat{f}(\gamma)=\int f(x)\gamma(x)dx$ or $\hat{f}(\gamma)=\int f(x)\overline{\gamma(x)}dx$ depending on his/her preference. The inversion formula will then be defined accordingly.